# Prove $-f'(x)$ using difference quotient?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Assuming the function $f$ is differentiable at $c$, I must show that:

$$\lim_{t\to 0}{f(c-t)-f(c)\over t}=-f'(c)$$

If I look at this graphically then I understand why the derivative would be negative, I'm just not sure how to go about proving this formally. Any suggestions?

Comment: Write the expression as $-[f(c+(-t))-f(c)]/(-t).$

Comment: It may be useful to let $t=-s$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(x) = f(-x)$,
so
$g'(x) = -f'(-x)$
or
$f'(x) = -g'(-x)$.

Then
$\frac{f(c-t)-f(c)}{t}
=\frac{g(t-c)-g(-c)}{t}
\to g'(-c)
=-f'(c)
$.